# AngularJS MVC4 not working with ngResource

Tags: javascript, vb.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, ngresource

I'm new to Angular.  The demo project I'm working on does not like my changes to use ngResource (instead of the $http or $q promise syntax)

When I click on the Courses link in the Registration.html below it begins calling the angular controller over and over until the browser crashes.
(also a bit of an oddity is the content of the Registration.html page is loaded over and over again into the ng-view div)

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Here are the pieces I think are relevant to the problem.

**Web.config excerpt**

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Registration" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^Registration"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="Registration.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

**Global.asax.vb**

```
Imports System.Web.Http
Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start()
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**WebApiConfig.vb**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization

Public Class WebApiConfig
    Public Shared Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
            name:="DefaultApi", _
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
        )

        Dim jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = New CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
    End Sub
End Class
```

**RouteConfig.vb**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Web.Routing
Public Class RouteConfig
    Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
        routes.MapRoute( _
            name:="Default", _
            url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )
    End Sub
End Class
```

...and now for the Angular stuff.  My main page is called Registration.html  This demo site has to do with a Student Class Registration -- thus the names
**Registration.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="registrationModule">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <title>College Registration</title>

        <!--------- Javascript Libraries --------->
        <script src="Scripts/UtilityJS/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>       
        <script src="Scripts/UtilityJS/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/UtilityJS/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/UtilityJS/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/UtilityJS/bootstrap.js"></script>

        <!--------- Application Libraries --------->
        <script src="Scripts/registration-module.js"></script>

        <!--------- CSS --------->
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/bootstrap-slate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!--------- Module Specific JS Libraries --------->
        <script src="Scripts/Courses/courses-controller.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Courses/courses-repository.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Instructors/instructors-controller.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Instructors/instructors-repository.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Accounts/accounts-controller.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Accounts/accounts-repository.js"></script>

    </head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="nabar-header">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><span class="navbar-brand">Registration</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/Registration/Courses">Browse Catalog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Registration/Instructors">Browse Instructors</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/Registration/CreateAccount">Create Account</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and for the sake of brevity I will add all the **Javascript** into one block but they are contained in separate files listed in the Registration.html  section.

```
var registrationModule = angular.module('registrationModule', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Courses', { templateUrl: 'Templates/Courses.html', controller: 'CoursesController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Instructors', { templateUrl: 'Templates/Instructors.html', controller: 'InstructorsController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/CreateAccount', { templateUrl: 'Templates/CreateAccount.html', controller: 'AccountController' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });


registrationModule.controller("CoursesController", function ($scope, courseRepository) {
    $scope.courses = courseRepository.get();
});

registrationModule.factory('courseRepository', function ($resource) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            return $resource('/api/Courses').query()
        }
    }
});

registrationModule.controller("InstructorsController", function ($scope, instructorRepository) {
    $scope.instructors = instructorRepository.get();

});

registrationModule.factory('instructorRepository', function ($resource) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            return $resource('api/Instructors').query();
        }
    }
});
```

and here's the results of the **api/Courses**

```
<ArrayOfCourseVm xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AngularTest3">
<CourseVm>
<Instructor>Ann Souloff</Instructor>
<Name>Intro to Comp-Sci</Name>
<Number>MIS101</Number>
</CourseVm>
<CourseVm>
<Instructor>Howard Meyers</Instructor>
<Name>Pascal Post-term</Name>
<Number>MIS201</Number>
</CourseVm>
<CourseVm>
<Instructor>Gary Baney</Instructor>
<Name>Data Structures using C</Name>
<Number>MIS301</Number>
</CourseVm>
</ArrayOfCourseVm>
```

This shouldn't be relevant but here's my **Templates/Courses.html** file

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span10">
        <h2>Courses</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span10">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>Course Name</th>
                <th>Instructor</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="course in courses">
                <td>{{course.number}}</td>
                <td>{{course.name}}</td>
                <td>{{course.instructor}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The part about loading the registration.html inside ng-view is interesting. Sounds like the url rewrite is kicking in. Can you check in browser dev tools to see what URL is actually requested to get back the contents of registration.html?

Comment: it's odd...  the `http://localhost:61307/Registration/Templates/Courses.html` is being loaded but the content is the Registration.html page.  It should be loading the /Templates/Courses.html so anything starting with Registration is being redirected to the Registration.html.

Comment: That's exactly what the rewrite rule is being told to do. Anything under `/registration` will be served the contents of `registration.html`. You'll need to move the templates out of `/registration` into the root of the site, then change the `templateUrl`s to '/Templates/Courses.html', etc.

Comment: Yup that worked.  Templates were already at the root.  I only had to add the / before Templates as you said.   Thanks!!!